# how to passing values by URL?

Tags: jquery

I need to access this content via URL:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  var inPlayPreferences = {"InplayPreferences":{"MarketOrder":[],"OpenedMarkets":[],"SportOrder":[],"FavoriteEvents":[],"OpenedUpcomingSports":[],"OpenedEvents":[3799712],"NavigationPanelViewMode":1,"IsUpcomingContainerOpened":false,"IsInPlayContainerClosed":false,"LastVisitedEventId":"3799712:1150","OpenedLiveNowSports":[1150,1154,1219],"IsTutorialEnabled":true,"IsPopularitySorted":true,"VisibleLiveNowSports":[],"VisibleUpcomingSports":[],"QuickBetStake":0,"CalendarLastVisitedInplaySport":"","CalendarLastVisitedUpcomingSport":"","ShowQuickBetMessage":true,"HighlightLastVisitedInplaySport":"","CurrentView":"single"},"AppPreferences":{"NoOfTopExpandedSport":3,"CheckEventCountToExpand":5,"CalendarEventCountLimit":10,"ExpandTopEvents":3,"EventNameTruncationLimit":30,"ParticipantTruncationLimit":20,"ComingUpHoursLimit":12,"EventUpdateRefreshRate":10,"LeftNavRefreshRate":16,"AllEventsRefreshRate":16,"CalendarLiveNowRefreshRate":12,"CalendarUpcomingRefreshRate":120,"FootballPitchEnabled":true,"FootballPitchRefreshRate":2,"TennisCourtEnabled":false,"TennisCourtRefreshRate":0,"CanDisplayTennisStatistics":false,"TennisScoreboardRedesignEnabled":false,"PriceUpdateRefreshRate":16,"PriceUpdateEnabled":false,"Col3CheckMarkets":6,"Col3OpenMarkets":2,"EventUpdateMode":1,"ClosedEventsDelay":300,"MarketContainerConfig":,"CloseQuickBetWindow":5,"QuickBetEnabled":true,"RightNavRefreshRate":60,"ScoreboardRefreshRate":5,"ScoreboardRefreshEnabled":false},"CurrentOddsFormat":"EU","IsDiffusionEnabled":false,"InPlayAppServiceName":"/services/InPlayApp.mvc/","InPlayCalendarServiceName":"/services/InPlayCalendar.mvc/"};
  var layoutController = null;

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var root = jQuery.fastFindById('inplayApp');
  layoutController = new SB.inPlayApp.LayoutController(root);

  });
</script>
```

I'm trying to pass data directly via the URL to make a paser:

> http://pt.sportingbet.com/services/InPlayCalendar.mvc/GetUpcomingEvents?MarketOrder=&OpenedMarkets=&SportOrder=&FavoriteEvents=&OpenedUpcomingSports=&OpenedEvents=&NavigationPanelViewMode=1&IsUpcomingContainerOpened=false&IsInPlayContainerClosed=false&LastVisitedEventId=4013383:1150&OpenedLiveNowSports=1150,1154,1219&IsTutorialEnabled=true&IsPopularitySorted=true&VisibleLiveNowSports=&VisibleUpcomingSports=&QuickBetStake=0&CalendarLastVisitedInplaySport=&CalendarLastVisitedUpcomingSport=&ShowQuickBetMessage=true&HighlightLastVisitedInplaySport&CurrentView=single

But the site returns me an error!
How should I pass this  javascript data via URL?

**ERROR OBTAINED:**

> 500 - Internal Application Error Sorry, there's been an error with the
>   application.
>
> What would you like to do?
>
> Return to the homepage Go back 1 step If you'd like to report an error
>   you can contact our customer services here

Comment: Your data is passed properly as per the URL you have given. Can you show some server side code parsing it??

Comment: Unfortunately not.
But if the code is passed correctly, why is it displays the error 500?

Comment: It may be a server side error while parsing. Debug the server code, I am sure you will find the reason of error 500,

Comment: Assuming you are using Apache, the log should show you the reason for error code 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer, just a long comment.

If you cannot show us your code, then simplify your problem. Create a test page with a very very simple version of testing your $_GET[] string:

```
http://pt.sportingbet.com/services/InPlayCalendar.mvc/GetUpcomingEvents?MarketOrder
```

In your PHP file, just parse the get string and alert the variable value (or print it to screen).

If that works, then add another component of your project and get that working.

It's a bit of work, but much faster than waiting for one of us to answer, especially when we can't see the back-end code.